# Is there any analogue for Java Collections.singleton() in C++?

Tags: c++, collections

In Java, I can construct a collection of single element by calling:

```
Collection<String> c = Collections.singleton("foo");
```

Is there a similar one-liner for `std::vector` or `std::set` construction in C++ (in Boost or whatever)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but there is also no need for it. In C++11 you can leverage the compiler's magic support for [`std::initializer_list<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) (and the new `vector` constructor that accepts one) by simply writing

```
vector<string> vec { "foo" };
```

The same goes for `std::set`.

Comment: and that? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/pool/doc/implementation/singleton.html

Comment: @Theolodis: You confuse the meaning of "singleton" in the question and in the page you linked. The question says "singleton" as in "a collection with just a single item" while what you linked to is the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). It's not the same thing. Even if it were, "and that?" is not an argument I can parse.

Comment: That would work just fine! Unfortunately, I'm on C++0x yet, and `std::initializer_list` is not available to me. But that's a nice answer anyway.

Comment: Works fine with `-std=gnu++0x` gcc option.